# Entity Plane in Cesium

Tags: javascript, box, cesiumjs, normals, plane

I am bit confused on how to get the Plane of an entity in CesiumJS. Basically I have a box with lat,long,height, 3 orientation angles. How can I draw and see the plane of this box from the information that I have(coordinates and orientation of the box) in Cesium ? and possibly get the normal of the plane.

Comment: what is the plane of the box?

Answer (score 0):

@zhefengJin
Basically I added the box to Cesium this way. Sorry for adding the code here and not in the comment reply.

```
position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(10.540573, 52.284086, 2);
var head=Cesium.Math.toRadians(90);
var pitch = Cesium.Math.toRadians(0.0);
var roll = Cesium.Math.toRadians(90);

var hpr = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(head, pitch, roll);
var orientation = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(position, hpr);

var blueBox = viewer.entities.add({
    name: "abc.JPG",
    description: `Location: ()`,
    position: position,
    orientation : orientation,
    box: {
      dimensions: new Cesium.Cartesian3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0),
      material: '/images/abc.JPG',
     },
});
```